# Odoo 14 models how to access to a particular record or the current record inside a function?

Tags: python-3.x, self

Greetings to all in this family. I'm new in odoo development which is very nice also.
I want to create a new module based on several related models.
During the development of a model the object **self** represent a recordset instead of the current record like **this** in java class or **self** in python class.
My question is how can i proceed to write a function in a model class that work on the current record.
Thanks in advance for all answers.

Answer (score 2):

`self` in odoo may or may not contain recordset(s) depend on the context you're working with.

For example

```
class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    _name = 'example.model'
    _description = 'Example'

    def print_number_of_recordset(self):
        # Print number of recordset in the self instance

        print(f"Number of recordset: {len(self)}")
```

If you're calling the method `print_number_of_recordset` from a form view like so:

```
<button string="Click Here" name="print_number_of_recordset" type="object"/>
```

it will print out `Number of recordset: 1` in the console because in you're working with 1 recordset in form view.

On the other hand if you're calling the method using other mean, for example:

```
recordsets = self.env['example.model'].browse([1,2,3]) # getting 3 recordsets provided that you have 3 recordsets of the same ID
recordsets.print_number_of_recordset()
```

it will print out `Number of recordset: 3` because in that instance the object `self` contains 3 recordsets